# Mapping with XML and RestKit

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, restkit, cocoapods

Since I upgraded [RestKit](http://restkit.org) and started using [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org) my old mapping ceases to work since all the values are now nested in a dictionary.

Is there a more elegant way to do a RestKit mapping for XML (I am aware that JSON is the main line of attack for RestKit but XML is not going to disappear anytime soon either.

#### Mapping before updating

```
[mapping mapAttributes:@"username", @"password", @"firstName", @"lastName", nil];
```

#### Mapping now with the `.text` suffixes

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"username.text" toAttribute:@"username"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName.text" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName.text" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
```

#### My Podfile

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'RestKit', '0.10.3'
pod 'RestKit/ObjectMapping/XML', '0.10.3'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 0.20.0 version of RestKit.

A wiki is available : https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0

Comment: I don't know if XML mapping is available in 0.20.0